# Recycler View Adapter with EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Ok, my problem is saving inputs of edit text.
I have a recycler view with some edit text inside. I have an adapter and button "add" to add another new edit text. There is a problem because if I write something inside one edit text it doesn't always save when I change focus or I cick on "add" button.

Here is my hosting fragment:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new AddPlayerAdapter(players);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

addButton.setOnClickListener {
    // overrides
    players.add(new Player(""));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So now, after click on "add" button new Player class is added to class Players (item players) and adapter is notified, I see on my screen that new item is added (declared in AddPlayerViewHolder). It works fine.

Here are fragments of my adapter class:

```
public AddPlayerAdapter(Players players) {
    this.players = players;
}

@Override
public AddPlayerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_player, parent, false);
    return new AddPlayerViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AddPlayerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.name.setText(players.get(position).getName());

    holder.name.setHint("Player " + Integer.toString(position+1));

    holder.name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (view != null) players.get(position).setName(holder.name.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

So each time focus is changed field is updated and it should contain actual data.

But, when I put some data in one edit text, then press "start" button (which open another fragment with "players" data) the focus don't lose and data is not updated. So, I think the idea with OnFocusChangeListener is wrong, but I don't see here anything better.

Could anyone of you make me an example of proper update data inside edit text boxes like here?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is common problem, hope someone will be interested in solution.

You can simply add TextWatcher to save entered player name.

```
public class EditTextSaverWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private Player player;

    public MyTextWatcher(Player player) {
        this.player= player;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Another option is to save name here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        player.setName(s.toString());
    }
}
```

To add the text watcher, you should use

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextSaverWatcher(concretePlayer));
```